# How to append key name with the parent key name in python

Tags: python, nested-attributes, key-value

Trying to write a python script to clean up the output from a characterization tool. I am struggling to solve an issue that no doubt has a very easy fix. The original data looks like this:

```html
Green:
      min: 73 (0.286275)
      max: 197 (0.772549)
      mean: 150.193 (0.588991)
      standard deviation: 12.6065 (0.0494373)
      kurtosis: 8.5551
      skewness: -1.44749
      entropy: 0.623078
```

I would like the output to look more like this:

```html
Green min: 73 (0.286275)
Green max: 197 (0.772549)
Green mean: 150.193 (0.588991)
Green standard deviation: 12.6065 (0.0494373)
Green kurtosis: 8.5551
Green skewness: -1.44749
Green entropy: 0.623078
```

Rather than specify the string that I'd like to appear prior to the key (e.g. append with "Green"), I'd like to generate this new name based off of how the keys are nested (e.g. append with parent name, which is "Green"). The reason for this is when formatting and separating key-value pairs (which I will split by the ":") I want to ensure that I do not lose the integrity of the data during a crosswalk and want to replicate this task throughout the report as needed (such as when I want to do the same for Red and Blue Channels, for example).

Is there a simple way to do this? Can't find any examples on here yet. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  If you'd like help with code, then share what you've done.

Comment: Looks like YAML. You might want to take the easy way, and parse it, then output the desired result using a library (for example http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

Answer (score 0):

```
old_dict = { ... }
new_dict = {}

for outer_key in old_dict:
    for key, val in old_dict[outer_key].iteritems():
        new_dict['{} {}'.format(outer_key, key)] = val
```